# FluentNHibernate - Getting the entity name when mapping. Current method being made obsolete

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am currently automatically naming my tables in fluent NHibernate by using AutoMappingOverride's and setting the name of the table to the pluralised name of the entity like so.

```
public class PersonMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Person>
    {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<Person> mapping)
        {
            mapping.Table(mapping.EntityType.Name.Pluralize());
            mapping.Id(x => x.PersonId).Column("PersonId").GeneratedBy.Increment();
            mapping.Map(x => x.Name).CustomSqlType("nvarchar(200)");
        }
    }



  public static string Pluralize(this string input)
        {
            return System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService.CreateService(new CultureInfo("en-US")).Pluralize(input);
        }
```

I am getting the following error.

'FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ClasslikeMapBase.EntityType' is obsolete: 'Do not call this method. Implementation detail mistakenly made public. Will be made private in next version.'

Does anyone know the correct way of getting the entity name? I've done a fair bit of Googling and have only found examples of people using this obsolete method to achieve what I need.

Cheers

### Steve

Thanks for all the great help guys. Using conventions is way more elegant for my use case than the overrides anyway.

```
var sqlConfig = MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(ConnectionString);
            var config = Fluently.Configure().Database(sqlConfig);
            config.Mappings(c => c.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<User>(new IJAutomappingConfiguration()).Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<TableNamingConvention>())); 




  public class TableNamingConvention : IClassConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Table(instance.EntityType.Name.Pluralize());
        }
    }
```

Here is the full code to get this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you would do it using a Convention:

```
public class NamingConvention : IClassConvention
{
    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Table(instance.EntityType.Name.Pluralize());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe trying Conventions, [FluentNHibernate Conventions](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions)